# What is the easiest way to import edge list data from a set of parquet files?

Tags: parquet, memgraphdb

I've been working with a collection of files that are stored in Amazon S3, which happen to be in the parquet format. These files represent the edges of a graph I'm working on, and are structured with the following fields: `src_id`, `dst_id`, and `weight`.

Is there a convenient and straightforward method for importing this data into Memgraph without having to go through the hassle of converting the files to CSV format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the the moment Memgraph supports (public key auth) [via GQLAlchemy](https://memgraph.com/docs/gqlalchemy/how-to-guides/table-to-graph-importer) (Python + PyArrow). At the moment there is no native integration (C++) for loading parquet files from S3 as is exists for loading CSV files.